# Converting SAS datetime to UNIX timestamp in SAS

Tags: mysql, sas

I'm trying to convert a SAS datetime to a UNIX timestamp but am getting an 8 hour difference in my results.  I think it's somehow related to a timezone issue but I can't figure out how.

To start with I ran the following statement in mySQL to get the desired result.

Query:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01 00:00:00') AS wanted_unix_timestamp
```

Result:

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01 00:00:00')  
---------------------------------------
                             1483221600
```

I then tried to write SAS code to convert a SAS datetime into that number but it seems to be 8 hours off:

```
%let wanted_unix_timestamp = 1483221600;

%let sas_epoch = '01jan1960:00:00:00'dt;
%let unix_epoch = '01jan1970:00:00:00'dt;
%let unix_timestamp_offset = %sysfunc(intck(seconds,&sas_epoch,&unix_epoch)); 

%let sas_datetime = %sysfunc(dhms(%sysfunc(mdy(1,1,2017)),0,0,0));

%let unix_timestamp = %eval(&sas_datetime - &unix_timestamp_offset);

%put &=sas_datetime;
%put &=unix_timestamp_offset;
%put &=unix_timestamp;
%put %eval(&wanted_unix_timestamp - &unix_timestamp);
```

Result:

```
SAS_DATETIME=1798848000
UNIX_TIMESTAMP_OFFSET=315619200
UNIX_TIMESTAMP=1483228800
-7200
```

Based on some google searches my offset seems to be correct.  I've also tried setting the session timezone in mySQL to different timezones to see if that makes a difference by using `SET SESSION time_zone = 'US/Pacific';` and `SET SESSION time_zone = 'Europe/Helsinki';` but they make no difference to the output.

**Edit:** I'm using SAS 9.4 so if there's an easier way to go about this then I'd happily take that as the answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost certainly being affected by the timezone, because `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` returns the current time as seconds from `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`.  Hence the 8 hour difference (being in the Pacific timezone).

Per [mySQL reference on session time zones](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html), setting the session timezone does *not* affect `UTC_TIMESTAMP`, and while it doesn't mention `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` directly, it presumably has the same non-effect there.

Comment: not a MySQL person, but I think he can combine this with the `CONVERT_TZ()` function to back out the UTC offset.

Comment: Makes sense, I'm not really a MySQL person either so hesitant to suggest specific fixes but that does seem like it should work.

Comment: @RobertPenridge - if Dom's solution works, i'll happily edit it into my answer (or you or Dom can feel free to post a separate answer), just let us know.